# sharepoint -use a lookup field to get an image

Tags: sharepoint

I have a picture library in sharepoint.

i have a list and want to use a lookup field to get an image from the picture library (which is also a list)

how do i get access to the actual image url using a lookup field?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the url you're after will be in column 'LinkFilenameNoMenu'

The UI won't let you reference that in a lookup, but creating the lookup in a Feature Receiver might. (There are issues creating lookups in plain CAML in a Feature so a Feature Receiver is usually required).

Answer (score 0):

You Can create custom field for rendering the picture as users select images